# Write a Class with Methods

Tags: javascript, class, methods

I'm trying to work on writing a class that has some methods in it. and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have the following test that I need to look at in order to create this class:

```js
'use strict';

const Editor = require('../editor');
const { expect } = require('chai');

describe('Editor', () => {
  it('allows users to write text', () => {
    const editor = new Editor();

    editor.write('Hello - codez');
    expect(editor.toString()).to.equal('Hello - codez');

    editor.write('moar');
    expect(editor.toString()).to.equal('Hello - codez moar');
  });

  xit('allows users to undo writes', () => {
    const editor = new Editor();

    editor.write('Hello - codez');
    expect(editor.toString()).to.equal('Hello - codez');

    editor.write('Moar stuff');
    expect(editor.toString()).to.equal('Hello - codezMoar stuff');

    editor.write('Even more');
    expect(editor.toString()).to.equal('Hello - codezMoar stuffEven more');

    editor.undo();
    expect(editor.toString()).to.equal('Hello - codezMoar stuff');

    editor.undo();
    expect(editor.toString()).to.equal('Hello - codez');

    editor.undo();
    expect(editor.toString()).to.equal('');
  });

  xit('allows users to find and replace', () => {
    const editor = new Editor();

    editor.write('foo stuff');
    editor.write(' other foo');
    editor.replace('foo', 'bar');
    expect(editor.toString()).to.equal('bar stuff other bar');
  });

  xit('allows undo replaces', () => {
    const editor = new Editor();

    editor.write('foo stuff');
    editor.write(' other foo');
    editor.replace('foo', 'bar');
    expect(editor.toString()).to.equal('bar stuff other bar');

    editor.undo();
    expect(editor.toString()).to.equal('foo stuff other foo');

    editor.undo();
    expect(editor.toString()).to.equal('foo stuff');
  });

  xit('allows users to redo', () => {
    const editor = new Editor();

    editor.write('foo stuff');
    editor.write(' other foo');
    editor.replace('foo', 'bar');
    expect(editor.toString()).to.equal('bar stuff other bar');

    editor.undo();
    expect(editor.toString()).to.equal('foo stuff other foo');

    editor.undo();
    expect(editor.toString()).to.equal('foo stuff');

    editor.redo();
    expect(editor.toString()).to.equal('foo stuff other foo');

    editor.redo();
    expect(editor.toString()).to.equal('bar stuff other bar');
  });
});
```

I wrote the following codebut I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or where to go from here. Can someone please help and tell me what is going on on the test and what I'm expected to do. :

```js
 class Editor {
  constructor (str) {
    this.str = str;
  }

  write(text) {
      let newSentence = text + this.str;
     console.log('This is the this str', newSentence);
  }

  toString(){
  
  }
}
```

Comment: this.str+=text; ... toString(){ return this.str;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Editor {
  constructor (str) {
    this.str = str;
    this.states = [""]; //for undo
    this.undos = [];
  }
  write(text) {
    this.undos = [];
    this.states.push(this.str);
    this.str += text;
  }
  undo(){
    this.undos.push(this.str);
    this.str = this.states.pop() || "";
  }
  redo(){
    if(this.undos.length){
      this.states.push(this.str);
      this.str = this.undos.pop();
    }
  }
  replace(a,b){
    this.states.push(this.str);
    this.str = this.str.split(a).join(b);
  }
  toString(){
    return this.str;
  }
}
```

You need to keep a history of your editors string...

Comment: Thanks for writing that Jonas. Can you explain a little more on how you arrived at creating the states and undo arrays? Your solution is great. I want to make sure I understand what it is doing.

Comment: @ivonne terrero to undo changes, you either keep track of them ( quite complicated) or just store all states. The last state we stored will be restored when undoing, so its *First in Last out* => we need a stack ( push/pop). The same principle applies on the redo.